# Does libpng allow to read not the whole image to the memory

Tags: c, png, libpng

I know that `libJPEG` can read not the whole image, using `jpeg_read_scanlines` .

Does `libPNG` have such opportunity? I see only `png_read_png` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at  [`png_read_row()`](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3.8) and `png_read_rows()`?

Bear in mind that this could have complications if the PNG is interlaced.